# How to fix "Element 2 of `.l` must have length 1 or 13, not 8" error in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I am writing a custom function that would allow me to make several separate boxplots. The x-axis should always be months, however the y-axis should take multiple values and the code should draw a separate boxplot for each case. When I try to run the code written below I get the following error: "Error: Element 2 of `.l` must have length 1 or 13, not 8". Can you explain why this error is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

```
forestfires <-read.csv(url(
     "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-  databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv"))

boxplot_months <- function(a,b, mydataset) {
  ggplot(data = mydataset) +
    aes_string(x=a, y=b) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white")) +
    labs(x=a, y=b)
}

indices_vect <- c("FFMC", "DMC", "DC","ISI","temp","RH", "wind",     "rain")
args_list <- list(a="month",b=indices_vect, mydataset=forestfires)

pmap(args_list, boxplot_months)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `pmap` expects your list of inputs (`.l`) to each have the same length. In your case `a` has length 1, being a single string. `forestfires` has length 13 (the length of a df being the number of columns).

Since anything of length 1 can be vectorised to a longer length by repeating, it expects your other list element, b, to have either length 1, in which case both a and b are replicated 13 times, or to have length 13, in which case only a is replicated.

In your case, you actually don't need `pmap` at all, just `map`, because the only input that changes each time through is `b`. If you change your last line to:

```
map(.x = indices_vect, .f = boxplot_months, a = "month", mydataset = forestfires)
```

Everything should work and you get your 8 plots. This makes use of the `...` argument in `map`, where you can specify other arguments to the `.f` function that aren't changing as you go through the `.x` list.